# clipping behaviour of ortho camera while looking at object intersecting others

Tags: camera, orthographic

I'm in solid shading mode. I have a grey cube object (as ground or plane) then i add 2 identical cube (red and blue). The blue cube is sitting on top of the plane . The red cube is located a bit lower so it cross/intersect the plane. i add ortho cam on top of both cubes, looking down. i  view through the camera and see both cubes and plane. The camera have a 'clip start' set to close to 0 (any small number may do).

Now when i will move the camera down slowly until the clipping starts to occur.

If both cubes is sitting or above the plane , everything is normal. But since the red cube is crossing/intersecting the plane, the clipping looks incorrect for that red cube. The red cube will be dissapeared as soon as the camera clip touch the cube while the blue cube is still visible.

it may be explained as : when the clipping has passed through the top face of the red cube, it will see the plane, so make an illusion that red cube is gone. Am i right ?

But this is not the look that i want to achieve, i want the red and blue still visible regardless that red is intersecting the plane, just because logically they're still on top of the ground. Is there anything i can do ?

I can achieve this using boolean cutter, but the real objects is a very complex house , consists of many smaller elements stored in many different collections, so i don't want to deal with boolean.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You mentioned you don't want to deal with a boolean, but it's worth noting that Blender 2.91 now supports targeting a collection (rather than an object) from a boolean modifier. If you have a master collection that includes everything relevant, you could target that from a Difference boolean on the plane.

Comment: That's some Eevee limitation, it seems (not the same using Cycles).

Comment: @TheTrueJard not close, i need the other way around. The new collection boolean 2.91 is really cool but it use collections as cutter, so you can group objects as complex cutter. My case is the opposite, i use a simple big box as a cutter to cut a complex object.  So i need collection for the object to be cut , not the cutter.

Comment: @lemon yes i need it for displaying in solid mode. In cycle, the volume is correct , the cube will be treated as 'solid' cube, so it looks like we cutting the cube layer by layer. But in solid mode or eevee, the cube is just hollow , so when camera come and clip the top face, it will directly see the ground. Since the side face is having 'no thickness' , looks like the cube is dissapeared.